# How to save choco packages locally?

Tags: windows, installation

We have few choco packages to be installed as dependency to our application. So, we are running the choco install commands before our installation created using installshield.

But now, customers are asking for installation without the need of internet access, for lockdown environments.

I tried setting up local choco server but it requires license to setup and which is not feasible for us to tell the customers to setup their own server by buying choco license.

How to download the choco packages locally and get their commands used in the background to keep the setup files as part of our installation.

Or any other alternative for this scenario.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried setting up local choco server but it requires license to setup
> and which is not feasible for us to tell the customers to setup their
> own server by buying choco license.

Why not? Choco paid has features to support local software mirrors and making package building easier. Purchasing also helps the company making this tool continue to exist.

Decide how much you need to be involved with how these dependencies are installed. Are you always calling choco, or can you skip the step and let them install things how they want? Are you responsible for selecting and providing [internal choco hosting](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/features/host-packages) or are they? Who is  [altering packages for internal use](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/create/recompile-packages)?

However packages are delivered, get experience in doing so. Firewall a host from the internet. Test and document a procedure for installing. If not using choco paid, fine, get creative. Install a libre Chocolatey server. Extract install commands from the package and install it without choco.

Comment: I didn't find any links for free version of choco server. You mentioned libre chocolatey server, Can you share any links for that.